# Can anyone offer any help with this function?

Tags: php, functions, search

I am trying to write a function for my functions.php file. I has to do the following;

- loop through search results and check the template
- if the template is 'landing.php' add it to ad array
- use the id's collected in the array to exclude these pages from the search results.

I found some code on the Wordpress Codex forum, I have added a little bit myself but unfortunately don't know what i'm doing...

```
function filter_where($where = '') {
global $wpdb; // do I need this?
if ( is_search() ) {
    if(is_page_template('landing.php')) { echo 'yes!'; } // ids collected here
    $exclude = array(286);  

    for($x=0;$x<count($exclude);$x++){
      $where .= " AND ID != ".$exclude[$x];
    }
}
return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter you are using `posts_where` affects the creation of SQL query, so by definition it is executed before query runs and you have any search results.

So you cannot loop through results at this point, what you can do is retrieve or hardcode list of unwanted items from elsewhere and use them to modify query.

**Update**

Ok, this is faster to code than trying to solve with comments. This is probably not perfect but should be good starting point for what you want:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages');

function exclude_pages( $query ) {

    if( !empty( $query->query_vars['s'] ) ) {

        $pages = get_posts(array(
                            'post_type' => 'page',
                            'meta_query' => array( array(
                                'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                                'value' => 'landing.php',
                            )),
                           ));

        $exclude = array();

        foreach( $pages as $page )
            $exclude[] = $page->ID;

        $query->set('post__not_in', $exclude);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to loop through my pages first and get the id's by template, then parse them to this function?

Comment: @Dan I don't think you want to mess with looping at all here. Since template is essentially value in `_wp_page_template` custom field you can just fetch all pages iwth template directly, using [meta query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: I'm not sure how that will fit in with the search feature....how about just getting the results and THEN sorting out the template? Or, what about using the filter to not get posts with a certain template? I haven't looking in the database recently to see how they are related - no doubt it won't be simple...

Comment: @Dan there are multiple ways to do this, but none that I can think off are very novice-friendly... Maybe using [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook would be less messy that dealing witg with SQL.

Comment: Im trying to write some code to test the template in the loop, after I have the returned posts. Do you know what function I need?

Comment: That worked a charm. I google'd set() and looked it up in the Codex and found very little info in it, same goes for $query->query_vars['s']. Do you know anywhere I can read up some more about how it works? I assume the "s" is for search queries?

Comment: @Dan those are internal `WP_Query` stuff, related function wrappers are `get_query_var()` and `set_query_var()`. See [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) in Codex. And yes `s` is argument for search, checking for it so non-search queries are not affected.

Comment: Ok, that sounds great. I have switched using WP_Query quite a bit lately, instead of query_posts. This should prove very useful. Thank you for taking the time to write, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove some specific pages or posts from your search results, you can easily do this using the "[WP Hide Post](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-hide-post/)" plugin.

According to its description: "Enables you to control the visibility of items on your blog by making posts/pages hidden on some parts of your blog, while still visible in other part."

In particular, this plugin allows you to control the visibility of a **post** in various different views:

- The Front Page (Homepage, depending on your theme, this may not be relevant)
- The Category Page (listing the posts belonging to a category)
- The Tag Page (listing the posts tagged with a given tag)
- The Authors Page (listing the posts belonging to an author)
- The Archive Pages (listing the posts belonging to time period: month, week, day, etc..)
- **The Search Results**
- Feeds

The posts will disappear from the places you choose them to disappear. Everywhere else they will show up as regular posts. In particular, permalinks of the posts still work, and if you generate a sitemap, with something like the Google XML Sitemaps the post will be there as well. This means that the content of your post will be indexed and searchable by search engines.

For a WordPress **page**, this plugin also allows you to control the visibility with two options:

- Hide a page on the front page (homepage) only.
- Hide a page everywhere in the blog (**hiding the page in the search results** is optional).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, if possible i'd like to do this without a plugin - I'm trying to understand this stuff so I can use it again : )   Im just trying to read up on functions a bit